# How to export proper TSV?

Tags: r, csv

Short and sweet: how can I export TSV/CSV from R?

`write.table` / `write.csv` *almost* works:

```
test <- data.frame(a = 2 : 4, b = 3 : 5)
write.table(test, file='test.tsv', quote=FALSE, sep='\t')
```

```bash
$ more test.tsv
a   b
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5
```

… but produces a format that is different from what’s expected by most other programs:

```
    a   b
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5
```

– note the different handling of the header row.

How can I export the second rather than the first format? Manually specifying the `col.names` as `c('', colnames(test))` doesn’t work – R complains about an invalid argument.

Comment: I'd argue that theres no definition of "proper" for csv or tsv files, just a bunch of different conventions.

Comment: @Spacedman I agree, hence my clarification in the question “what’s expected by most other programs”.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `col.names = NA`:

```
write.table(test, file='test.tsv', quote=FALSE, sep='\t', col.names = NA)
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph  I agree that this is one of those weakly documented "gotchas."  On the bright side, once you've learned it you never forget :-)

Comment: @Carl Despite your promise, I forgot it again. :-/

Comment: don't you really want row.names = FALSE?

Comment: One can say many things about R, but "intuitive default options" is not one of them.

Comment: I had a followup question. col.names says I can specify a vector as my column names. But frustratingly I've not been able to get it to work. I've tried adding a tab at the beginning with `names = c( c("\t"), colnames(test) )`, then adding that column names as `col.names = names`. This intuitively should work, but why doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry to resurrect, but @DaveH is right, I think you want `row.names = FALSE` and `col.names = FALSE`, not `NA`.

Comment: Geez, I love R. To solve `<basic intuitive problem X>` just set `<important parameter Y> = missing value`.

Comment: There are a few comments here about using `col.names=FALSE` or `col.names=NA` and the difference is that using `FALSE` *prevents* the colnames from being written to the file *at all*, while using `NA` *does* include the colnames in the file but prepends the first row of the file (ie, the colnames) with a tab character, so that the colnames actually line up with the proper data. For the question posed, using `NA` gives the desired result.

Answer (score -2):

you could also consider excluding the row names `row.names = FALSE`

Comment: From the expected output OP obviously wants to keep the row numbers. And this is already suggested above in the comments.