# Writing big dataframe into txt file

Tags: r, sink

I have a dataframe s. I would like to write its content into an outputfile.txt
When I use the following commands:

```
> sink ("outputfile.txt") 
> s
> sink()
```

I get the following message:

```
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5162 rows ]
```

How can I write all the content of this dataframe directly into a txt file?

Comment: what about using `write.table`, does this work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t use `sink` to write table data to files, use the appropriate functions instead. In base R, that’s [`write.table`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html) and its sibling functions. Unfortunately the function has some rather questionable defaults — but the following for instance should work:

```
write.table(data, filename, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE, col.names = NA)
```

`sink` is generally only useful to capture output from functions that don’t return their output but rather echo it directly to the console (such as warnings and messages).

Comment: @neerajt `col.names = NA` is intended, please do not attempt to edit it out. [Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17108191/1968)